# Grid Layout with equally height rows in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

### Jetpack Compose:

I want to create a grid layout like UI with equally height rows, but I can't find a function for getting the current usable screen size ([The application should look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTMQb.png))

### How the result should look like:

[Have a look at the link mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTMQb.png)

### What I have tried:

I tried to use `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` inside of **LazyVerticalGrid** for generating equally sized rows, but it didn't work. Beside of that, I also had the idea of setting the height manually for every row item, but I couldn't find a function for getting the usable screen size in jetpack compose (I then would have divided the screen height by the number of rows).

```
val numbers = (0..34).toList()

LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(7)

) {
    items(numbers.count()) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "#"+numbers.get(it))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @or_dvir the answer of the user "Code Poet" worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can measure screen height this way:

```
val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp
```

But it might be worth your making your grid scrollable using a scroll modifier:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#scroll-modifiers

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will try this as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [aspectRatio](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).aspectRatio(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)) modifier:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp),
) {
    items(100) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)
        ) { }
    }
}
```

Full example:

[image]

```
@Composable
fun Body(modifier: Modifier) {
    Column (
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Without aspect ratio",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
        )
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        ) {
            items(100) {
                Surface (
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(12.dp),
                    color = Color(0xff2187bb),
                ) {
                    RandomSizeBox()
                }
            }
        }
        Divider()
        Text(
            "With aspect ratio",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
        )
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        ) {
            items(100) {
                Surface (
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .padding(12.dp),
                    color = Color(0xffbb2187),
                ) {
                    RandomSizeBox()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RandomSizeBox() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.height((10 + Math.random() * 90).dp))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case this solution is not really practical, because my main goal was to make a calendar view, which means that I always know the number of rows and of course one month must always match exactly the height of the screen.

But thanks anyway :) By the way, for anyone interested, I finally managed to get things done by using the answer of the user "Code Poet" bellow (just forgot to mark his answer).

Answer (score 6):

there is another perhaps simple way to do it. You could keep tab of which item is the highest at the moment and update all the other one accordingly. Here is an example:

```
var desiredItemMinHeight by remember {
  mutableStateOf(0.dp)
}

val density = LocalDensity.current

LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(count = 2),
) {
        items(state.items) {
            ItemBox(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .onPlaced {
                        with(density) {
                            if (desiredItemMinHeight < it.size.height.toDp()) {
                                desiredItemMinHeight = it.size.height.toDp()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = desiredItemMinHeight),
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, `onSizeChanged` might be a better fit as it will be only called as many times as there is a larger item detected. Advancing on this solution, how would you handle changing data and potentially storing higher than needed height? I assume some sort of invalidation will need to take place.

Comment: Yep that might work too, one idea for the invalidation is to use the dataset of items as key for the remember which keeps the minimum height, so each time the data set changes it will force the remember to reset itself again.

Comment: Nice, this solution works fine if you want to modify all the items together, but is possible to improve it only for each item in the same "row"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use subcompose layout to precalculate the max height of the biggest view, and then use that height for all of the LazyVerticalGrid items.

For example:

[image: example]

**How does this work?**

SubcomposeLayout gives you constraints, i.e. the max width and height the view could be. You can use this to calculate how many views will fit for a given min width. I will use 128 dp:

```
val longestText = exampleStringList.maxBy { it.length }
val maxWidthDp = constraints.maxWidth/1.dp.toPx()
val width = maxWidthDp/floor(maxWidthDp/128)
```

Then you can measure the height of a test view, in my case CategoryButton passing the calculated width from above to the modifier:

```
val measuredHeight = subcompose("viewToMeasure") {
        CategoryButton(
            longestText,
            modifier = Modifier.width(width.dp)
        )
    }[0]
        .measure(Constraints()).height.toDp()
```

Next you compose your actual LazyVerticalGrid, ensuring that the items use the height you calculated above:

```
val contentPlaceable = subcompose("content") {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 128.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        ) {
            items(DataStore.categories) { category ->
                CategoryButton(
                    category,
                    onClick = { onCategorySelected(category) },
                    modifier = Modifier.height(measuredHeight)
                )
            }
        }
    }[0].measure(constraints)
```

And finally, layout the LazyVerticalGrid:

```
layout(contentPlaceable.width, contentPlaceable.height) {
        contentPlaceable.place(0, 0)
    }
```

Full code:

```
SubcomposeLayout { constraints ->
        val longestText = DataStore.categories.maxBy { it.length }
        val maxWidthDp = constraints.maxWidth/1.dp.toPx()
        val width = maxWidthDp/floor(maxWidthDp/128)

        val measuredHeight = subcompose("viewToMeasure") {
            CategoryButton(
                longestText,
                modifier = Modifier.width(width.dp)
            )
        }[0]
            .measure(Constraints()).height.toDp()

        val contentPlaceable = subcompose("content") {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 128.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
            ) {
                items(DataStore.categories) { category ->
                    CategoryButton(
                        category,
                        onClick = { onCategorySelected(category) },
                        modifier = Modifier.height(measuredHeight)
                    )
                }
            }
        }[0].measure(constraints)
        layout(contentPlaceable.width, contentPlaceable.height) {
            contentPlaceable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
```